# How to write proper/efficient query

Tags: postgresql

I have a question about the right way of writing the query.

I have an employees table, lets say there are 4 columns `employee_id`,  `department`, `salary`, `email`.

There are some records without email address, I'd like to find the most efficient way to write SQL query using window function that brings the sum salary per group, divided by all of those without email address.

I have 2 solutions, of course only one is efficient, can anyone give any advice about it?

```
select department, sum(salary) as total
from employees
where email is null
group by 1
```

option 1

```
select a.department , a.total/(select sum(salary) from employees where email is null) 
from (
  select department, sum(salary) as total
  from employees
  where email is null
  group by 1
) a
```

option 2

```
select a.department , a.total/sum(a.total) over()
from (
  select department, sum(salary) as total
  from employees
  where email is null
  group by 1
) a
```

I guess that query 2 is more efficient, but is it the right way? and is it valid to leave over clause empty?

Just started using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is better.

The first query has to scan `employees` twice, while the second table only scans the (hopefully smaller) result set of the subquery to calculate the sum.

It is perfectly valid to leave the `OVER` clause empty, that just means that all result rows will get the same value (which is what you want).